# Horizontal line under header background

Tags: header-footer, rules, wallpaper

I made a function that displays a header background. However, there supposed to be a horizontal line right under the background image, that goes from very left to very right with no margins.

This is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wallpaper}

\newcommand{\BackgroundHeader}[3]{%
  \AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
      \parbox[b][\paperheight]{#1\paperwidth}{%
        \includegraphics[width=#1\paperwidth,height=#1\paperheight,%
                         keepaspectratio,trim={#2},clip]{#3}%
        \vfill%
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\BackgroundHeader{2}{0 1650 550 1625}{background.png}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

I've tried putting following under `\vfill`, but no results:

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}%
```

What I'm doing wrong? How to get that line under the image?

Comment: `\vfill` puts it at the bottom of the page, doesn't it? If you colour it red, you can just see it on the edge of the page.

Comment: But also you have made the image twice `\paperheight` high. So the rule is going to be `2\paperheight` down from the top of the page.

Comment: Maybe you want something like `\newcommand{\BackgroundHeader}[3]{%
  \AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
      \parbox[b][\paperheight]{#1\paperwidth}{%
        \includegraphics[width=#1\paperwidth,trim={#2},clip]{#3}%
        \par%
  \vfill
  \noindent\makebox[\paperwidth]{\color{red}\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}%
  \bigskip
  \par
      }%
    }%
  }%
}`?

Comment: @cfr I think you should turn your comments into an answer :-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The trouble is, I'm not sure what it is meant to look like. How big should the background image really be and where should the line really go?

Comment: Updated with the image of the actual page. As you see, there is nothing at the bottom of the page. As I wrote, *this is the header*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line should be under the header image you have to put it before `\vfill`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wallpaper}

\newcommand{\BackgroundHeader}[3]{%
  \AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
      \parbox[b][\paperheight]{#1\paperwidth}{%
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=7\baselineskip
          ]{#3}% <- necessary to avoid spurious spaces
        \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
        \textcolor{red}{\rule[-2pt]{\paperwidth}{2pt}}%
        \vfill%
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\BackgroundHeader{3}{}{example-image.pdf}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Note that I have changed the options for `\includegraphics` because I do not have your picture.

If the image should be part of the page style you could also use package `scrlayer`, see [Fancy header and footer including images with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245432/43317)